# java synchronized fails to synchronize

Tags: java, multithreading

How do I synchronize the run method?
If I use the synchronized keyword here, it doesn't work. It gives me a different output every time?

```
class MyClass implements Runnable 
{
    boolean flag;
    public MyClass(boolean val)
    {
       flag=val;
    }
    public synchronized void run()  
    {
        long id=Thread.currentThread().getId();
        int start=(flag)?1:2;
        for(int i=start;i<=10;i+=2)
        {
           System.out.println("Thead "+id+" prints:"+i);
        }
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Thread t1=new Thread(new MyClass(false));
        t1.start();
        Thread t2=new Thread(new MyClass(true));
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you recognize that it doesn't work or what do you expect to happen? There is nothing that gets accessed outside the class so it's hard to judge.

Comment: the threads are interfering when printing

Comment: Well, that's what threads are for. I think you chose the wrong solution to your problem. The threads won't interfer each other if you use run() instead of start() but than you don't have any reason to use threads.

Comment: To synchronize, you need to synchronize on the same object, but you are not doing that.

Comment: Please show us the output by pasting it into the question as text.

Comment: thanks everyone,i re-wrote the code using synchronized on object level.it worked

Answer (score 2):

Each thread is using a different instance of MyClass. If you use synchronized on a non static instance, this ensure the method is not executed by several threads  at the same for the same MyClass instance. If you want to synchronize for all instances of MyClass, the method has to be static.

```
class MyClass implements Runnable {
    
    boolean flag;

    public MyClass(boolean val)
    {
       flag=val;
    }  

    private static synchronized void runTask(boolean flag) {
        long id=Thread.currentThread().getId();
        int start=(flag)?1:2;
        for(int i=start;i<=10;i+=2)
        {
            System.out.println("Thead "+id+" prints:"+i);
        }
    }

    public void run()  
    {
        runTask(flag);
    }

}
```

Comment: It should read "... not executed by several threads *at the same time* for the same `MyClass` instance."

Comment: how do i do synchronization for all objects of the same class?i cant make the run method static here

Comment: The synchronization can be applied to any object, including a special-purpose `Object` instance used just for that purpose.

Comment: you can call a static method declare with synchronized keword inside the run method

Comment: Synchronization on a class is almost never a good idea.

Comment: yes for sure, it is better to share a lock or a monitor object